# Backup and restore Elasticssearch data without running the Elasticsearch service

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, centos, centos7

Is it possible to backup Elasticsearch indices and data and restore later after new OS installation without running the service? my server is facing an issue which all files and folders owner were accidentally changed to root user and subject for new OS installation. I can run `service elasticsearch start` but it fails, checking via `service elasticsearch status` it return this

[image]

and when to check Java, it return this

[image]

so I decided to go reinstall OS and wondering if I can backup Elasticsearch indices and data and restore it later after the installation. What can I try next?

I tried to look for /var/lib/elasticsearch/data but data folder does not exist

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to change the permissions of the elasticsearch folders to the elasticsearch user? You can try to backup the entire data folder, which is `/var/lib/elasticsearch/data` if installed using packages, and start your new instance keeping the same cluster and node name.

Comment: @leandrojmp found no data folder in /var/lib/elasticsearch/ any ideas?

Comment: How did you installed elasticsearch? If it is not in `/var/lib/elasticsearch` then it seems that you didn't use the packages (deb or rpm) or the directory was changed in the `elasticsearch.yml` file, look into this file to see if the path is there. If you used the `.tar.gz` file the data folder is inside the directory where elasticsearch was installed.

Comment: @leandrojmp not sure about the installation because its was those tech guys who manage my server installed elasticsearch but found elasticsearch.yml on the "/etc/elasticsearch" and saw this line "path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch" any ideas?

Comment: Correcting myself, the default data directory is `/var/lib/elasticsearch/`, which seems it is what you are using, should be a folder named `nodes` inside `/var/lib/elasticsearch`, this is your data and is what you could try to backup. But, have you trying to change the permissions of the folders already?

Comment: @leandrojmp yes, doing "ls -l" shows "elasticsearch elasticsearch", I can conclude this is a java problem because doing "java --version" throws me error "could not create the java virtual machine" and doing "service elasticsearch start" returns an "OK"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213507/discussion-between-juliver-galleto-and-leandrojmp).

Comment: @leandrojmp 
saw the node folder inside /var/lib/elasticseasrch
so moving this folder to a backup folder will do? and then move them back again to the data folder to new elasticsearch installed will do?

Comment: It should work, but it is not guaranteed, this is a last resort way to backup elasticsearch. You should try to fix the permissions first and see if the service is starting and your data is accessible and not corrupted, whatever happened in your server could have affected your elasticsearch data.